# How Do I return a DataTable from a SubSonic Query?

Tags: subsonic

I'm trying to return a datatable from a query I have written in Subsonic (I'm just starting to learn it) - But can only return a DataSet?

```
public DataTable GetAllCarTypes()
{
    return new Query("tblCarType").ExecuteDataSet();
}
```

I was hoping for .ExecuteDataTable()??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only returning 1 table from the query, you can do:

```
public DataTable GetAllCarTypes()
{
    return new Query("tblCarType").ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Ugly but correct. SubSonic definitely needs ExecuteDataTable(). Why anyone uses a DataSet when they only need a DataTable is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhaaa.. should have thought about it before O posted, think I have it now

```
public DataTable GetAllCarTypes()
{
    return new Query("tblCarType").ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
}
```

If not please can you post up the correct syntax